# Error viewing the same page on localhost

Tags: php, cakephp

My ctp file code :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Users',array('action'=>'port_settings_edit')); ?>

<tr><td><center><?php echo $this->Form->input('process',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$pid,'id'=>'pid')); ?>
<?php echo $pname; ?></center></td><td><center>
<?php echo $characteristic; ?></center></td><td><center>
<select id="deviceid"></select></center></td><td><center><select id="instid">
<option value="">Select Any</option>
<option value="xyzz">xyzz</option>
<option value="fgh">fgh</option>
<option value="abc">abc</option>
</select></center></tr></table>
<BR><BR> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="bott1"><font size=3 ><b>SUBMIT</b></font></button>
```

- **function defined in my controller :**

  ```
  function port_settings_edit($id=null)        
  {
      $this->loadModel('Process');
      $op=$this->Process->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Process.id'=>$id)));

       $this->set('pname',$op['Process']['name']);//ERROR
       $this->set('pid',$op['Process']['id']);//ERROR
       $this->set('characteristic',$op['Process']['characteristic']);//ERROR
       if(!empty($this->data))
       { 
         //$this->layout = false; 
         //print_r($this->data);
         $this->Session->setFlash('PORTS SETTINGS ARE DONE SUCCESSFULLY.');
         $this->redirect(array('action'=>'viewport'));              
       }
  }
  ```

I am encountering the same error on these 3 lines. i.e

> undefined syntax: process

I have already defined the variables.

Comment: please show your process modal code

Comment: @Anant, Process is looks fine, because its model name of CakePHP

Comment: Oh my bad . in the function please write very first `echo "<pre/>";print_r($this->request->data);` and check what it prints. it will show you the form data in array format and it will tell you clearly what is wrong in your code. check one. if that not work write `print_r($_POST);` and check

Comment: which lines are giving the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issue in your CakePHP code.

1. in method you have passed **$id**, and form action url is also wrong it should be `<?php  echo $this->Form->create('Users',array('url'=>['action'=>'port_settings_edit',$pid]));?>`
2. Also no need to pass $pid in hidden field because you are fetching from url.

Also please mention which error exactly you are facing.

Comment: This is not working.Actually if i pass number instead of $id in the controller it is working fine. ie $op=$this->Process->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Process.id'=>5))); But with $id it is not working.Why?

Comment: yes, its working fine because currently $id have null value.. can you please check action URL of form tag using inspect element?

Comment: i think it's taking $id=null inthis.How to correct this

Comment: hello dear, you are facing error when posting form or loading page?, if you fecing error on loading page then you have not passed id in url, have to pass id in url like your_app_url/controller/port_settings_edit/5, if you facing error on for submission then check id is passing on action url or not.

Comment: id is passing in the form url Users/port_settings_edit/70 but when i fill the entries on the page it should redirect to view_port but it is not going

Comment: return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'viewport'));

Comment: unfortunately, now i cant help you more... but still check form method is GET or POST? If you dont mine my skype is haresh.vidja for more help